Distribution of scattered photons in cone-beam computed tomography (CBCT)
I am using MCGPU to simulate photon transport in cone-beam computed tomography (CBCT). I ran an experiment, where a water cylinder containing spherical objects was irradiated. The simulation software allows for separate collection of the distribution of primary and scattered photons in the detector. Here are the pictures showing the photon energy distribution ($\dfrac{\text{ev}}{\text{cm}^2}$) across the pixels (200x200). The left shows the true signal, while the right shows only the scattered photons.

This would mean that the distribution of scattered photons follows a Gaussian distribution. This is interesting, but does it make sense in the real world; which I would like to simulate accurately.
If we consider this situation from the point-of-view of the central limit theorem (CLT), then the distribution should indeed be a Gaussian. Consider the position of a photon on the detector (x,y coordinates) as a single random variable. A very large number of individual photons is simulated, which is to say that our sample size (number of random variables) $n$ is approaching infinity.
The CLT now states, that the distribution of the sample mean follows a Gaussian distribution. Therefore the observed distribution is justified. Also, the angular distribution of scattered photons is sufficiently random, so it is valid to consider the position of a scattered photon as a random variable.
Is this a valid explanation for the observed scatter distribution?

I suspect this image visualizes just how your simulator models the scattered photons, and it seems this model is a simple Gaussian independent of the object.
If I remember correctly, the scattered photons are scattered off the electrons they may meet on their way (Compton scattering). But then I would expect that the probability of a photon to get scattered would be angle-dependent (I refer to the ray angle), as different rays pass different distances inside the object and then the scattering probability is different.

Is that a side view of the cylinder? … should the image be end on instead for the true signal?

@PhysicsDave I forgot to mention that this is the data from a single projection angle, not a full reconstruction

I assume you know about photon shot noise as well. No source of photons is predictable or constant. Sqrt of the signal is the noise/ variation.
